# Dart: able to add 2 but not 1

Tags: integer, dart, integer-overflow, arbitrary-precision

I'm testing this snippet in DartPad:

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  int ov = pow(2, 53);
  ov = ov + 0;
  print('$ov');
  ov = ov + 1;
  print('$ov');
  ov = ov + 2;
  print('$ov');
}
```

I'm new to Dart. I was trying to overflow the variable, but apparently Dart has arbitrary precission integers. The output is kind of surprising:

```
9007199254740992
9007199254740992
9007199254740994
```

Why am I able to add 2 but adding 1 does not have any effect?

Here is [the pad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/7b84a01acb9f3eae8f19ec6c54734a61) if you want to check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dart is compiled to JS it relays on JS Number type for *num* (*int* or *double*). If you try the same things in a JS console you will get the same results:

```
> Math.pow(2, 53)
9007199254740992
> Math.pow(2, 53) + 1
9007199254740992
> Math.pow(2, 53) + 2
9007199254740994
```

Comment: I see. So the problem is with JS's [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

Comment: Yes, precisely, and the fact that DartPad is based on the dart2js compiler which compiles to JavaScript.